# Is it okay to feed Brussels sprouts to a bearded dragon?

Tags: diet, reptiles, bearded-dragon

I saw a Facebook comments thread about this. Some people said sprouts aren't that healthy for them because there are too many vitamins. Other people said it was dangerous to feed them sprouts at all.

What is the actual situation? Are Brussels sprouts safe to feed to bearded dragons, or not?

Comment: (I don't actually have a beardie myself, but it made me curious.)

Answer (score 3):

Brussel Sprouts contain high levels of [goitrogens](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goitrogen), a chemical substance which interferes with iodine intake and can lead to hyperthyroidism. These are safe for a beardie to consume in moderation - collard greens and turnip greens [among others](http://www.blackninjakitty.com/herps/care/troystuttlegreeniglist.htm) contain high goitrogen levels too, and yet these are the staples of a beardie's diet.

The key is moderation -  Brussels are full of vitamins but are not suitable as a long-term regular food.

[More info on goitrogens](http://www.moonvalleyreptiles.com/uromastyx/uromastyx-diet/oxalates-goitrogens-toxins).

Answer (score -1):

As I have seen in my research, it seems like a lot of it has been if you want to feed a Bearded dragon Brussels, you would do it rarely. In addition to feeding a Bearded dragon Brussels rarely, here's a list on what you would rarely feed a Bearded dragon.

> Rarely
>   Broccoli, Brussel sprouts, Carrots, Cauliflower, Green peas raw, Rutabaga raw, Tomatoes, Pomegranate, Star fruit, Bananas, Rice brown long grain, Soybeans

http://www.lovebeardies.com/information/bearded_dragon_food_and_nutrition.html

For more information click the link above for more foods.

On more research, like stated above Brussels do have high ammounts of goitrogen.

> Can Bearded Dragons eat Brussel Sprouts?
>   Yes, rarely, high in vitamins but also has goitrogen
>
> Goitrogens – Inhibits intake of Iodine that then causes problems with the Thyroid Gland such as swelling.

https://www.beardeddragon.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=200150